# Which class connects mapreduce job to its dataset in hadoop source code?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I've read the classes in `hadoop-common/src/util`, but I can't find the class which relates the job to its dataset.

How does Hadoop know which map reduce job relates to which dataset?

Answer (score 0):

This is determined by the InputFormat.

More precisely: each MapReduce job is assigned an implementation of `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat` (see `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job#setInputFormatClass`), which is used by the framework to determine the input splits (= the input 'dataset').

You can search for the key `mapreduce.job.inputformat.class` in order to check which implementation has been used in your job, and of course set your own implementation.